# Yaml use a key as block and value

Tags: yaml, rails-i18n

I don't know if what I'm looking for is possible but I have the following YAML

```
en:
  log:
    model1:
      update:
        description: "My description for update"
        variable1:  "something"
        variable2:  "something else"

    model2:
      update:
        description: "My description for update"
        variable3:   "another thing"
        variable4:   "still different"
```

I would like to be able to replace this `t("log.model1.update.description)"` by this for having the same result
`t("log.model1.update")` and later still able to do this `t("log.model1.update.variable1)`

I want to avoid to create a description key for each action of each model

Is their a way to have something more dry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML 1.1 had an optional [value key](https://yaml.org/type/value.html) that would work like this:

```yaml
en:
  log:
    model1:
      update:
        =: "My description for update"
        variable1:  "something"
        variable2:  "something else"

    model2:
      update:
        =: "My description for update"
        variable3:   "another thing"
        variable4:   "still different"
```

It's unlikely that this is supported out-of-the-box (though I don't know – fell welcome to try) but since this is valid YAML, you can use this idea to shorten your query to `t("log.model1.update.=")`.